# Prolog : Type error: `evaluable' expected, found `[]' (an empty_list)

Tags: prolog

I am trying to delete elements from a list which satisfy a given constraint. The user inputs a budget and items having price greater than the budget are deleted. I am  getting a type error when consulting the file.

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

main(_) :- 
   write('Enter budget'),
   nl,
   read(Budget),
   write(Buget),
   numlist(1,168,MasterList),
   BudgetList is [],
   apply_budget(MasterList, Budget, BudgetList),
   write(BudgetList).

apply_budget([],_,_).
apply_budget([H | T], B, R) :-
   price(H, Pr),
   (Pr > B ->
       apply_budget(T, B, R);
       append(R, [H], L),
       R is L,
       apply_budget(T, B, R)
   ).
```

Comment: Your program is written in an imperative way, you for instance write `append(R, [H], L)` and later `R is L`. This will always fail, since you can only assign a variable one in Prolog, and a list can not be equal to alist with an element added to it.

Comment: Willem is spot on. You've written this entirely as if this were an imperative language. You simply can't delete elements from a list in Prolog. In Prolog everything is immutable. If you've got a list then the list **cannot** be changed. You can only create new things. So if you want to delete elements from a list you would create a new list without the elements you want to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written this entirely as if this were an imperative language. You simply can't delete elements from a list in Prolog. In Prolog everything is immutable. If you've got a list then the list cannot be changed. You can only create new things. So if you want to delete elements from a list you would create a new list without the elements you want to delete.

Here's how you should write your `apply_budget` predicates:

```
apply_budget([],_,[]).
apply_budget([H|Ts],B,Rs) :- price(H, P), P > B, !, apply_budget(Ts,B,Rs).
apply_budget([H|Ts],B,[H|Rs]) :- apply_budget(Ts,B,Rs).
```

The first is the case when the have an empty list in then you don't care about the budget and an empty list should come out.

The second is the case when the value `H` is greater than `B` so we throw away `H` and recurse. The `!` (cut) is there to prevent back-tracking so that the third predicate isn't tried if we have failure.

The third is the case when `H` is less than or equal to `B`. In this case we keep `H` by building (not deleting) it on to the output as `[H|Rs]`.

The cut could have been removed by writing the code this way:

```
apply_budget([],_,[]).
apply_budget([H|Ts],B,Rs) :- price(H, P), P > B, apply_budget(Ts,B,Rs).
apply_budget([H|Ts],B,[H|Rs]) :- price(H, P), P =< B, apply_budget(Ts,B,Rs).
```

I think that becomes less manageable, but you can decide which you like better.

Comment: Why no if-then-else after `price/2`?

Comment: @false - Because there is a difference in the head of the predicate - `Rs` vs `[H|Rs]`.

Comment: @false - I end up with `apply_budget([H|Ts],B,Zs) :- (H > B -> Zs = Rs else Zs = [H|Rs]), apply_budget(Ts,B,Rs).` in Strawberry Prolog. I don't feel it looks as clean. But it certainly works.

Comment: s/else/;/ it is at least much more efficient, and I would say it is very clean

Comment: @false - How do you measure the efficiency?

Comment: Your first attempt re-executes the head twice - and your second one will execute price/2 twice and leave a CP open for each case taken by the first alternative.

Comment: @false - That's another good reason for the cut. I always thought that Prolog is pretty efficient at executing multiple heads. It's an O(1) lookup from memory.

Comment: The cut above is highly problematic - in the case when `H` is a variable.

Comment: @false - True, but so is the `H > B` comparison.

Comment: No, `H > B` is perfectly safe: If the arguments are not sufficiently instantiated, the system stops with an instantiation error. So you do not get incorrectly small answers as with the cut-version.